# google app engine stringlist property on Database

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I want to create a database in google app engine with the following properties

```
class Questions(db.Model):
    title = db.StringProperty()
    author = db.StringProperty()
    text = db.TextProperty()
    date = db.DateProperty(auto_now_add = True)
    votes = db.IntegerProperty()
    answers = db.StringListProperty()
    tags = db.StringProperty()
```

The problem is that when I go to the dashboard and try to create an entity from there, answers property isn't there.

Is there any better way to have a list of strings, so I can manipulate them seperately?

Update:

When I try to update the entity and add something on the string list:

The link is localhost:9082/questions-4889528208719872

```
class QuestionPageHandler(BaseHandler):
    def get(self, *a, **kw):
        sURL = self.request.url.split("-")
        question = Questions.get_by_id(long(sURL[-1]))
        self.render_content("questionpage.html",question=question)

    def post(self, *a, **kw):
        answer = self.request.get("answer")
        sURL = self.request.url.split("-")
        question = Questions.get_by_id(long(sURL[-1]))
        question.answers.append(answer)
        question.put()  **<---- I forgot to add this EDIT**
```

And then on the html I use this:

```
{% for answer in question.answers %}
   <div class="well span7">
      <p>{{answer}}</p>
   </div>
{% endfor %}
```

But I have an empty page.

Comment: You won't be able to use the datastore viewer for more than the most rudimentary types.  I suggest you use the remote_api_shell or write some code for your app.

Comment: What is BaseHandler.  If your using webapp2 you would normally self.response.write  what does self.render_content  do, 

does it call self.response.write ?

Comment: Sorry. I didn't mention it. Exactly what you say. On render_content I call self.response.write

Comment: Thank you  Tim. I find the problem. I edit the question and add the solution. Forget to add the "question.put()"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution:

```
def post(self, *a, **kw):
        answer = self.request.get("answer")
        sURL = self.request.url.split("-")
        question = Questions.get_by_id(long(sURL[-1]))
        question.answers.append(answer)
        **question.put()** <-- add this
```

Answer (score 1):

[Link to NDB](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/)

Maybe try NDB which has list type properties

look at ->

ndb.StringProperty(repeated=True)
or
ndb.StructuredProperty(xxx,repeated=True)